# Elasticsearch: Limit filtered query to 5 items per type per day

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to gather data for my frontpage on my event-portal. the current query is as follows:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "geo_distance": {
              "distance": "50km",
              "location": {
                "lat": 50.78,
                "lon": 6.08
              },
              "_cache": true
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "and": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": "event"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "datetime": {
                        "gt": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "not": {
                  "term": {
                    "type": "event"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "functions": [
       ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So basically all events in an 50km distance which are future events or other types. Other types could be status, photo, video, soundcloud etc... All these items have a datetime field and a parent field which account the items belongs to. There are some functions after the filter for scoring objects based on there distance and age.

Now my question:
Is there a way to filter the query to get only the first (or even better highest scored) 5 items per type per account per day?

So currently I have accounts which upload 20 images at the same time. This is too much to display on the frontpage.

I thought about using filter scripts in a post_filter. But i am not very familiar with this topic.

Any ideas?

many thanks in advance

DTFagus

Comment: Perhaps this is really helpful: http://www.gridshore.nl/2014/07/25/playing-with-two-most-interesting-new-features-of-elasticsearch-1-3-0/

Comment: Yep, that's the one: do an aggregation and use `top_hits`.

Comment: I would not get it directly in the right format but I could build the correct one in my code aftewards i think. If it works i will get back here with the correct solution. Any ideas for a better implementation welcome!

Comment: You should be able to do exactly that. `top_hits` allows to provide a criteria for the "best" X number of matches. In the link you provided look at "Top hits with scripting" - it's sorting the results based on the score of each document.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it this way:

```
"aggs": {
    "byParent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "parent_id" 
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byType": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "type" 
          },
          "aggs": {
            "perDay": {
              "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "datetime",
                "interval": "day"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "topHits": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 5,
                    "_source": {
                      "include": ["path"] 
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately there is no pagination for aggregations (or other way around: the pagination of the query is not used). So I will get the paginated query results and the aggregation of all hits and intersect the arrays in js. Does not sound very efficient but I currently have no better idea. Anyone?

The only way around this I see would be to index all data into two indices. One containing all data and one with only the top 5 per day per type per account. This would be less time consuming to query but more time and storage consuming while indexing :/

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of results returned by your query using the "size" parameter.if you set size to 5, then you will get the first 5 results returned by your query.
Check the documentation http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Ymartin. Thanks for the answer, but that does not really help. I dont want to limit the whole query to 5 results. It should still return hundreds of results. But for each account there should be only 5 photos per day returned.